# Getting Date input from the user and passing as parameter using python

Tags: python, function, datetime, user-input

I have a query text file like,

```
Select * from emp WHERE empdate >= '%s';
```

I'm specifying the date and passing as a parameter inside the function using python, like

```
 DATE = "28-01-2019"
```

and I'm reading the query file and passing the DATE parameters to a function for pulling the data for the specified date.

So, I need to get the date input from the user and to pass that date for DATE variable and that should reflect on the query file.

SAMPLE:
When the user enter the date as `09-02-2019`
This should go inside the DATE and in the query file and the final output is to fetch the data for `09-02-2019`.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems did you run into?

Comment: What did you try already? Where is your problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you actual problem is. If what you are looking for is to read user input, you can use `input = input()` to get user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

date_input = input("Enter date: ")
while not re.match('\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}', date_input):
    date_input = input("Invalid date entered (dd-mm-yyyy), Enter date: ")

query = f"Select * from emp WHERE empdate >= '{date_input}';"

# Use your query wherever you need...
```

**NOTE:** This regex just validate the structure of 'dd-mm-yyyy' but doesn't validate that the date value makes any sense. Because you fetch from a DB it's ***probably*** fine, but not necessarily. **use it with caution**.